# Javascript: always execute function in execution context

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I wrote this fast-templating function:

```
var templatize = function(string) {
    return function (string) {
      return string.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(pattern, match) {
        value = this[match];
        if (value) {
          return value;
        } else {
          return pattern;
        }
      });
    }.call(this, string);
}
```

Which does this:

```
var foo = "bar", bar = "foo";
templatize("We are {{foo}} and {{bar}}, but not {{crazy}}"); // "We are bar and foo but not {{crazy}}"
```

I'm quite happy with this except that I have scoping problem. For sure, the `templatize` method will be accessible through namedscope, but then, the current context of execution of `templatize` is not accessible in my function automatically.

Something like calling `$.proxy(templatize, this)("We are {{foo}} and {{bar}}, but not {{crazy}}")` should work, right?

But I'd like to achieve this without needing to call $.proxy() (and without any jQuery preferably) so that context is automatically transfered to the execution one.

I'm struggling with `.call()`, `.apply()`, and other closures, but I think I read somewhere over the internet that it was possible. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the source code of mustache or handlebars for ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript OO reference this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282605/javascript-oo-reference-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you pass an object containing the view variables? would be cleaner then potentially displaying any existing variable in your view.

```
var templatize = function(string, variables) {
  return function (string) {
    return string.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(pattern, match) {
      value = variables[match];
      if (value) {
        return value;
      } else {
        return pattern;
      }
    });
  }.call(this, string);
}
```

Comment: At the end, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger You can remove this wrapper function : `return function (string) {...}.call(this, string);`, it does nothing.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Then you can replace the six lines inside the replacement function with a single one : `return variables[match] || pattern;`, which means "value OR pattern".

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using jQuery doing this :

```
var templatize = function(string) {
    var me = this; // the data source
    return string.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (full, key) {
        // "this" refers to the string itself
        return me[key] || full;
    });
}
```

In case you want to use `jQuery.proxy()`, wrap the replacement function :

```
var templatize = function(string) {
    return string.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, jQuery.proxy(function (full, key) {
        // "this" now refers permanently to the data source
        return this[key] || full;
    }, this));
}
```

In both cases you can bind the data source to `this` using `call` :

```
templatize.call({ hello: 'Hi!' }, '{{hello}}');
```

---

### Going further

You could optimize by compiling the template for reuse :

```
function compile(tpl) {
    var i = -1, tmp = [];
    tpl = tpl.split(/{{([^{}]+)}}/);
    while (++i < tpl.length) {
        if (i % 2) tmp.push('this["' + tpl[i] + '"]');
        else if (tpl[i]) tmp.push('"' + tpl[i].replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"');
    }
    return new Function(
        'return [' + tmp.join() + '].join("");'
    );
}
```

Usage example :

```
var tpl = compile('{{hello}} {{hello}}');
tpl.call({ hello: 'Hi!' }); // "Hi! Hi!"
tpl.call({ hello: 'Yo!' }); // "Yo! Yo!"
```

Regarding the example above, here is the function returned by `compile` :

```
function () {
    return [this["hello"]," ",this["hello"]].join("");
}
```

Note that you can use an array as well :

```
var tpl = compile('{{1}} {{0}}');
tpl.call(['a', 'b']); // "b a"
```

Performance test : http://jsperf.com/template-compiling.